# Is it possible to create an SSIS Package when I have only SQL Express 2008 and Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: ssis

I don't get the Business Intelligence Project type at all when I try to create a new project and I have looked for two days for a workaround. Is it just not possible to do this in VS2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This website](http://www.sqlis.com/post/SQL-Server-Editions-and-Integration-Services.aspx) says you can only build basic import and export SSIS packages through Management Studio for any edition below Standard.  Therefore, you won't be able to find SSIS in VS2008.

You can develop Reporting Services reports using **SQL Server Express with Advanced Services** in Visual Studios as [outlined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166.aspx).